# VS Code Extension designing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vscode-extensions

Need one help regarding vscode extension designing. So, I am designing a custom vs-code extension for a custom programming language, the syntax of this language is similar to python, but not fully. As everyone know in vs-code we can go to any symbol in current file by pressing **ctrl+shift+o**, eg if we want to go to any function. It works fine in my custom language when comes to function, but there is one more feature in my language, but I want that it scans the following expression also when finding symbols.

**Routine: myFunc**

Eg,

```
/*
 * Routine: myFunc
 */
myFunc = Func(int a)
Returns(int){
  a++;
  return a;
}
```

When I am pressing **ctrl+shift+o** it is showing **myFunc** as symbol, but in below code

```
myStruct = Structure(
  /*
   * Routine: myFunc
   */
  myFunc, callMyFunc(
    Print("Called my func");
  )
)
```

when I am pressing **ctrl+shift+o** it is not showing **myFunc**, I want my extension to show. Is there any way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to find a way to do that online, also read VSCODE extension Page, but didn't get any help.

Comment: It's not a simple task you are facing here. What you need is a parser for your new language, which provides information for each of the symbols (name, location in source code, semantic etc.). With that symbol information you can then answer all the requests for listing functions, showing definitions and code completion in general. However, this is too broad for a single question.